# IOS Device Logs

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-log

I recently made some changes to my app that was already on the app store, and a couple days later, I find that my new version gets rejected for crashing on launch. Which is strange because I tested it n an ipad air, and iphone 6 and an iphone 5 and it worked on all 3. I got the following crash log from apple and I was wondering if anyone could help me decipher where the error is, as this is my first time having such a nasty error.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000101380a1c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   resumeToolkit                   0x0000000101380a1c 0x10136c000 + 84508
1   resumeToolkit                   0x0000000101380a64 0x10136c000 + 84580
2   UIKit                           0x000000018cf15a00 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040
3   UIKit                           0x000000018cf155d8 -[UIViewController view] + 28
4   resumeToolkit                   0x000000010138aef4 0x10136c000 + 126708
5   resumeToolkit                   0x000000010138a5a0 0x10136c000 + 124320
6   resumeToolkit                   0x000000010138a664 0x10136c000 + 124516
7   UIKit                           0x000000018cf15a00 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040
8   UIKit                           0x000000018cf155d8 -[UIViewController view] + 28
9   UIKit                           0x000000018cf1c1a4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 136
10  UIKit                           0x000000018cf19404 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
11  UIKit                           0x000000018cf882e8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
12  resumeToolkit                   0x000000010139f4d0 0x10136c000 + 210128
13  resumeToolkit                   0x000000010139b464 0x10136c000 + 193636
14  UIKit                           0x000000018cf842c4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 384
15  UIKit                           0x000000018d175bc4 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3436
16  UIKit                           0x000000018d17aa14 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1712
17  UIKit                           0x000000018d4162a8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
18  UIKit                           0x000000018d6ee100 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
19  UIKit                           0x000000018d415f0c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
20  UIKit                           0x000000018d41676c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 732
21  UIKit                           0x000000018db9b7c0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
22  UIKit                           0x000000018db9b664 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
23  UIKit                           0x000000018d9092cc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
24  UIKit                           0x000000018daa23cc _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
25  UIKit                           0x000000018d90917c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252
26  UIKit                           0x000000018d6ed760 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
27  UIKit                           0x000000018d179158 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
28  UIKit                           0x000000018d58edbc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
29  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018601e1f0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
30  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000186026af8 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001832daa14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001832e2200 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
33  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001860527f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
34  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018605249c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
35  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000186052a38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
36  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018390377c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
37  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839036fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
38  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183902f84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
39  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183900b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
40  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183820c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
41  GraphicsServices                0x00000001856ccf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
42  UIKit                           0x000000018cf795c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
43  resumeToolkit                   0x00000001013750b4 0x10136c000 + 37044
44  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018334056c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183470d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582eec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183470d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582eec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183470d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582eec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018344f568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018344f3e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183903108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183900cd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183820c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x0000000184255594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001842749ac -[NSRunLoop+ 178604 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018dae37a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001843570f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835842b4 _pthread_body + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183584180 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b74 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183470d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582eec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018344f5bc semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001832dd000 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 84
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001832dd870 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001832e91d8 _dispatch_worker_thread + 256
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835842b4 _pthread_body + 308
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183584180 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b74 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001834700f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183586ce4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000182b26f34 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait+ 32564 (std::__1::unique_lock&, std::__1::chrono::time_point > >) + 96
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018acc9168 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until > >+ 10133864 (std::__1::unique_lock&, std::__1::chrono::time_point > > const&) + 124
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018acc903c std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration > >+ 10133564 (std::__1::unique_lock&, std::__1::chrono::time_point > > const&) + 108
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018acc8ec0 bmalloc::AsyncTask::threadRunLoop+ 10133184 () + 280
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018acc91b8 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy >, void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask*), bmalloc::AsyncTask*> >+ 10133944 (void*) + 44
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835842b4 _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183584180 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b74 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183470138 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183587660 _pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 96
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835875a4 _pthread_mutex_lock_slow$VARIANT$mp + 264
3   WebCore                         0x000000018b797f4c _WebTryThreadLock+ 278348 (bool) + 128
4   WebCore                         0x000000018b797eac WebRunLoopLock+ 278188 (__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 44
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183902cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183900694 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183900e38 __CFRunLoopRun + 1780
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183820c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
9   WebCore                         0x000000018b79584c RunWebThread+ 268364 (void*) + 560
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835842b4 _pthread_body + 308
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183584180 _pthread_body + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183582b74 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x000000018dca8460   x2: 0x0000000000000303   x3: 0x000000016ea90b68
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x000000016ea90fc8
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000010c000001ff
   x12: 0x0000000149019000  x13: 0x000005a1b47f9c4f  x14: 0xfffffffeb82c60bf  x15: 0x000000000000001c
   x16: 0x0000000101a3f138  x17: 0x000000018d8ffce0  x18: 0xfffffff01449925c  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000147d39f40  x21: 0x00000001014f6000  x22: 0x00000001c41e6100  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001c00df170  x26: 0x00000000000003c8  x27: 0x0000000148059978
   x28: 0x0000000000000350   fp: 0x000000016ea911c0   lr: 0x0000000101380788
    sp: 0x000000016ea91090   pc: 0x0000000101380a1c cpsr: 0x40000000
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log so you can see the exact line of code causing your issue. Then update your question showing that relevant code.

Comment: Isn't this already symbolicated?

Comment: Your own app's code isn't symbolicated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, the way I resolved this was by going to window -> organizer and then downloaded the DSYM of the version from which the crash logs were from. My problem was that for some reason the proper DSYM was not being used to symbolicate the code.